# How to configure nginx to act as a load balancer for proxies?

Tags: curl, nginx, proxy

I am aware that nginx can be configured to act as a load balancer, but I'm wondering if it is possible to load balance between proxies? Let's say I have multiple proxies running on localhost, and I want to use nginx to provide a single point of connection so that I can rotate between the proxies. I am trying to achieve something similar to the post [here](http://blog.databigbang.com/running-your-own-anonymous-rotating-proxies/), which is using HAProxy instead of nginx. I have the following `nginx.conf`:

```
events {  }

http {
    upstream proxies {
        server localhost:9998;
        server localhost:9999;
        server localhost:10000;
    }
    server {
        listen 8080;

        location / {
            proxy_pass http://proxies;
        }
    }
}
```

However, when I send a curl request like this:

```
curl http://icanhazip.com -x localhost:8080
```

It ignores the url, and I get a response similar to what I would expect if I had directly sent a request to one of the proxy servers like so:

```
curl localhost:9999
```

Of course, I did not really expect it to work, since there must be some option to tell nginx to treat the upstream servers as proxies themselves. However, I was not able to find how to do this after searching online.

Comment: I'm not sure of your problem, what is your problem, and what are you calling a proxy -- as here you nginx load balance is also a reverse proxy --? Is your problem the fact you have no host header? Try adding `proxy_set_header Host $host;` after ther proxy_pass instruction.

Comment: I am trying to use nginx to rotate between multiple proxies that I have set up. In other words, I want to be able to be able to connect to nginx host and port (ie localhost:8080) as a proxy, and it will rotate between the proxies that I've set up

Comment: Ok, and did you try the host thing? Because a reverse proxy is almost transparent, nobdy cares if the proxyied backend are final servers or also some proxy, but you need to know what domain you are actally forwarding to the proxy.

Comment: Tried it but didn't seem to work for some reason... On a side note, I was able to set up the same thing on AWS with an elastic load balancer and a cluster of EC2 instances, but I had to set up a TCP rule for the load balancer instead of HTTP in order for it to work. Not sure if this is also the case here?

Comment: Any idea if HAProxy has includes? I'd like to use that method you linked to but maintain the proxy list in a separate file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as you can see in your haproxy post haproxy akt as a **forward proxy**

> option http_proxy

What this option mean is described in the manual https://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/1.6/configuration.html#4-option%20http_proxy

> It sometimes happens that people need a pure HTTP proxy which
>   understands basic proxy requests without caching nor any fancy
>   feature. In this case, it may be worth setting up an HAProxy instance
>   with the "option http_proxy" set. In this mode, no server is declared,
>   and the connection is forwarded to the IP address and port found in
>   the URL after the "http://" scheme.
>
> No host address resolution is performed, so this only works when pure
>   IP addresses are passed. Since this option's usage perimeter is rather
>   limited, it will probably be used only by experts who know they need
>   exactly it. This is incompatible with the HTTP tunnel mode.

As far as I know nginx does not have this feature.

A similar question it this.
https://superuser.com/questions/604352/nginx-as-forward-proxy-for-https

Why can't you use the haproxy as described in the post of your link?

Comment: HaProxy doesn't allow you to include a file in a config. I want to manage a proxies.list file that is imported. Nginx does have includes, but apparently you can't forward requests to an http proxy?

Answer (score 3):

The nginx docs say upstreams are distributed using a round-robin method.

> By default, requests are distributed between the servers using a
>   weighted round-robin balancing method

https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_upstream_module.html

Answer (score 0):

You would need to configure load balancing rule for proxies either weighted or other

something like max_fails=1 fail_timeout=10s;

```
        Can you put max_fails =1 and fail_timeout=10s; after the proxies

    server localhost:9998 max_fails =1 and fail_timeout=10s;
    server localhost:9999 max_fails =1 and fail_timeout=10s;
    server localhost:10000 max_fails =1 and fail_timeout=10s;


  change location /{ 
       to location @proxy{
```

Comment: can you provide full example here?